# Best approach to define fixed data in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, design-patterns

I need help about how to handle fixed (not changing) data in Symfony, in an API architecture.

Let's say we are doing a dices game, and we want to store the list of dices, each one having a specific range of values (e.g. one having only odd numbers from 1 to 10, another one having only even numbers from 1 to 10, and a last one having all numbers from 1 to 6), and a label.

Creating DB tables to store the different values (e.g. Dice[id,label], DiceValue[id,dice_id,value]) doesn't seem to be the right solution here, so I'd prefer to define these dices in Symfony directly.

My question is how would you define those in Symfony ?

Using a Factory ? Tagged iterators ?

I can't find any resources on the *right* way to do this kind of things..

Thanks!

Comment: The concept of "dice" seems simple enough that I don't know if Symfony really needs to be "aware" of it in the first place? On the simplest level, you've just got three arrays. You could back that with classes if you want, I guess, and throw an interface on them with `GetDiceValues()` if you wanted to add more complexity. But I don't think Symfony  itself needs to store anything.

Comment: I'm not saying this is the path you should go down, but I think you could, and just make these simple services https://3v4l.org/kNLiL#v8.2.7

Comment: use a dice interface, with a `getValues()` method and a `const` for the name. implement the method for each case. use a `tagged_iterator` to import all dices to your services as needed.

Comment: I went with the @Rufinus solution since I wanted to use tagged iterators. Thanks to you both for your help :).